# Page works correctly in IE9 only after opening the console. Why?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, browser, internet-explorer-9, console.log

I have a web-page written using AngularJS. When I open it using IE9, the top menu's templates aren't executed at all. However when I open the developer console in IE9 and reload, it all suddenly starts working fine and keeps working even if I close the console.

Can it be due to some "clever" IE9 optimizations, which are disabled when the console is open?

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Is there something I can do about it? It seems impossible to debug it, since it works correctly when I am debugging it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's probably because you have used `console.log` used somewhere in the code which throws an error when the console is not active.